# How does tls 1.3 encrypt certificate in Server Hello to prevent eavesdropping?

Tags: tls

I know that `ESNI` and certificate encrytion in Server Hello are aimed at preventing eavesdropping from the hostname and `ESNI` hasn't been taken into practice for common web servers yet.

Even though, I am still curious about:

How does tls 1.3 encrypt certificate in Server Hello to prevent eavesdropping? And how does the client decrypt it and get the certificate?

I found a good post [A walkthrough of a TLS 1.3 handshake](https://commandlinefanatic.com/cgi-bin/showarticle.cgi?article=art080) but have some difficulty in reading it.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look here https://tls13.ulfheim.net/

Basically, server chooses cipher suite in Server Hello message.